# How to obtain the document Id of a newly added Firestore document in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I need to add the Firestore document id to the user document but after Googling for the past couple of hours I am none the wiser. The code I use to create the document follows:

```
try {
  String userId =
    await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(_email, _password);
  await addDocument('Countries/AU/user', {
    "userId": userId,
    "email": _email,
    "password": _password,
    "givenName": _givenName,
    "familyName": _familyName,
    "mobile": _mobile,
    "phone": _phone,
    "companyName": _companyName,
    "language": _language,
    "documentId": _documentId
  });
} catch (e) {
  print('Error: $e');
}
```

I then need retrieve it later when updating it by

```
Firestore.instance.collection('Countries/AU/user').
                   document(_documentid).get().then((docSnap){
  ...
}
```

I tried adding "DocumentReference docRef" in front of "await addDocument('Countries/AU/user'," but it caused a syntax error. There are other "reference number" type suggestions but none worked. I hope someone is able to help me. I have also tried "print(document.documentID)"

Comment: What is exactly is `addDocument`?  That doesn't looks like an actual Firestore API method.